# Read parameters from worklight.properties in html pages

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a worklight application(Worklight 6.2).

In this application i have requirement where certain parameters i need to read from worklight.properties file.

For worklight adapters i got success but i also require to read some parameters in html pages from worklight.properties file.

My question is,is it possible to read value from worklight.properties file from html pages?

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to say u want to access the worklight.properties file present inside the server/confi folder from HTML

Comment: yes this is what i exactly want

Comment: what you are trying to achive via HTML is not possbile and can u say me which property you need so that i can help you with anyother workaround

Comment: There are some URLs which i have hardcoded in html pages i need to read them from worklight.properties file.

Comment: Ill suggest you with a way since what you are expecting is not possible. First of all, as i understood ,you need to retrieve URL from server side and place it in the client side. So that the URL when changed in Server side it affects the client am i right.

Comment: Its very simple currently any change in URLs forces me to create new wlapp and deploying the same.I just dont want to take that pain.

Comment: can you look into my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of adpaters in this Scenario.

1. Have an HTTP adapter.
2. In that use the adaptername.js file to create variable and assign your URL. Have a procedure which send these values to your client side.
3. At the start of the application try to connect to your adapter and try to retrive the url from adapter and set as a global variable in your client js.
4. Then use that global variable where ever you want.

Comment: This is what i never wanted to do :).But anyways if there is no direct solution i will go ahead with this

Comment: @2intor still now we cant access the server side properties via any client side js :)

Comment: I was expecting a solution simmilar to JSTL.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.
You cannot read properties from worklight.properties inside your HTML file.

worklight.properties -> server-side
index.html -> client.side

Perhaps you should put these values in your JavaScript, then store them in the app's localstorage and update them via AJAX when required.